# I want to make a parking fee program by using visual studio

Tags: c

```c
    int min1, min2, won;

    printf("parking minutes(분)? ");
    scanf("%d", &min1);

    min2 = (min1 - 30) % 10;

    if (min1 <= 39) 
        won = 2000;
    else {
        if (min2 = 0)
            won = 2000 + 1000 * (min1 - 30) % 10;
        else
            won = 2000 + 1000 * (min1 - min2 - 20) % 10;
    }
    printf("parking fee: %d", won);
```

The conditions of this program

1. until 30min, 2000won
2. after 30min, 1000won per 10min
3. max 25000won per a day
4. parking minutes cannot be over than 24 hours

I thought that '%' means remainder so I write like that but when I input 52, the results say `5200`! I want to make result to be `5000`. And I want to know what to do for condition 3 and 4. What can I do? Should I use 'for' and 'sum'?

Comment: `if (min2 = 0)` should be `if (min2 == 0)`

Comment: @DDK If you learn to reverse the order of the items, you'll never have this problem. `if(0 == min2)`.  This way here if you forget an equal sign, the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's program the steps in the same order as the assignment:

```
int min1, min2, won;

printf("parking minutes(분)? ");
if (scanf("%d", &min1) != 1) {
    printf("invalid input\n");
    return 1;   // invalid input.
}

won = 2000; // 1. until 30min, 2000won, minimum price
if (min1 > 30) {
    // 2. after 30min, 1000won per 10min
    min2 = min1 - 30;  // minutes after 30
    // add 1000won for every slice or 10min or portion thereof
    won += ((min2 + 9) % 10) * 1000;
    // 3. max 25000won per a day
    if (won > 25000)
        won = 25000;
}
// 4. parking minutes cannot be over than 24 hours
if (min1 > 24 * 60) {
    // reject request
    printf("parking time exceeds 24 hours\n");
} else {
    printf("parking fee: %d\n", won);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the condition of your inner if in else block.

```
if(min2 = 0)
```

One equal sign is assignment operator, you have to use == for equality check.

```
if(min2 == 0)
```